# Breadth-first search with set instead of queue

Tags: graph, breadth-first-search

I'm using BFS to find connected components. I've decided to implement it using a set to track visited nodes. The problem with that approach is that one vertex may be added to queue twice. So I just changed queue to set. I don't care about visit order, all nodes are visited once and the algorithm works fine. Of course, this is not classical BFS anymore: the order is broken.

Pseudocode:

```
Set visited;
Set to_visit; 
visited.insert(start)
to_visit.insert(start)
while (to_visit is not empty){
    current = to_visit.first
    to_visit.delete(current)
    for each neighbour of current {
        isNew = visited.insert(neighbour)
        if (isNew) {
            to_visit.insert(neighbour)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm not the first one who "invented" it. I wonder: how does this I-dont-care-first search is called?

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to @A J's answer, a node can indeed be added to a queue twice.

For example take the graph with nodes 1, 2, 3 and edges 1-2 1-3 2-3. Node2, 3 are added to the queue while visiting node1, and then node 3 is added to the queue again while visiting node2!

To improve algorithm time, I prefer something like this. This code allows adding the same node to a queue, but it checks if the node is already visited, thus the algorithm doesn't have to perform the time-consuming process of checking all adjacent nodes of an already visited node.

```
    while(Q.size() > 0) {
        int q = Q.remove();
        if(visited[q] == false) {
            visited[q] = true;
            
            int size = V.get(q).size();
            
            for(int k=0; k<size; k++) {
                int val = V.get(q).get(k);
                if (visited[val] == false) {
                    Q.add(val);
                }
            }       
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How could it be added to the queue twice ? You must make sure that elements on queue are unique, if vertexs are objects add flag "visited=false", when you try to add vertex into queue you check flag first and proceed only if it's on false, then change it to true.

If vertexs are just a numbers, then create an boolean array representing flags for each vertex.

Pseudocode:

```
queue= []
set = [0,0,0,0,0....,0]
queue.push(firstVertex)

while(!queue.isEmpty())
{
     vertex curr = queue.pop()

     if(set[curr] == 1) //already visited
     {
          continue;
     }
     set[curr] = 1;
     foreach(child of curr)
     {
          queue.push(child);
     }
}
```

You can also change flag from true/false to number of component.

Comment: Thank you, I do know about proper implementation of BFS. Actually I'm doing the same, but maintain uniqueness of the queue by set. And in my implementation a vertex is visited when it _really_ visited, not when added to queue.

Comment: Yes, with set it should also work, just change isVisited to mySet[vertex] = 1 or something ? But the order is still the same. I see your problem! You can add an if statement on the beggining and check if curr has been visited yet or not. I change my pseudocode to your idea.

Comment: `if(set[curr] == 1)` tampers the complexity of the algorithm. One vertex can be considered more than once.

Comment: Than use one set to mark vertexes added on queue and one set for actually visiting vertex.

Comment: .... and this is exactly what I've done! But then queue itself is useless, because I can take nodes to visit from the set.

Comment: Can you provide me your source, i am not sure how would you remove queue from algorithm

Comment: Sets are most commonly implemented using binary red-black trees, where insert, delete and search take O(log(n)) on average and worst situation. Queue on the other hand are most commonly implemented using linked list where you know pointers to first and last element making pop and push O(1), search however works O(n) on the worst case, so i suggest you to make an array "visited" or add extra attribute if your vertexes are objects. Moreover add two arrays: one for visited and one for inQueue (or work with attributes)

Comment: What about unordered_set, implemented with hash-table? O(1) for all operations.

Comment: Hash table has averege time complexity O(1), but worst case are O(n) anyway. Well it depends on max number of vertexes and available time

Comment: Sure it does, but worst cases happens quiet rarely.